# Spring HATEOAS rename collection and items of third-party classes

Tags: rest, spring-hateoas

I'm writing a Rest API using Spring HATEOAS to expose third-party objects I'm not in control of - they are coming from a dependency.

Since I can't change the class directly and add an `@Relation` annotation, I was wondering if there's a recommended way to change the collection and item names using some other strategies.

I thought of using Jackson Mixins but doesn't sound to me like the right approach.

Thanks